# Python web-scraping into csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, rows, export-to-csv

I did a web-scraping, and I get a table which one I want to write into CSV.

When I try it, I get this message :

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Python27/megoldas3.py", line 27, in <module>
>   file.write(bytes(header,encoding="ascii",errors="ignore")) TypeError:
>   str() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)"

What's wrong with this code? I use Python 2.7.13.

```python
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

out=open("proba.csv","rb")
data=csv.reader(out)

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

maindatatable=""
soup = make_soup("https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok")

for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    datatable=""
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        datatable=datatable+","+data.text
    maindatatable = maindatatable + "\n" + datatable[1:]

header = "Penznem,Devizanev,Egyseg,Penznemforintban"
print maindatatable

file = open(os.path.expanduser("proba.csv"),"wb")
file.write(bytes(header,encoding="ascii",errors="ignore"))
file.write(bytes(maindatatable,encoding="ascii",errors="ignore"))
```

Comment: `bytes` will take only one parameter

Comment: i understand the error message, but i dont know how i have to correct it.

Comment: `encoding="ascii",errors="ignore"` are the attributes if write function not of bytes, I posted the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about encoding your strings before trying to write them?

```
utf8_str = maindatatable.encode('utf8')
file.write(utf8_str)
```

Also don't forget to file.close()

Comment: It is work, but look at the excel file. 
There are 3 empty row, and there is some format issue + this is not delivered :S 
http://kepkezelo.com/images/r8iq7bhnsop59l5hrh02.png

Comment: Then you probably need utf16 for HU. http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/. So your code should simply switch utf8 to utf16.     utf16_str = maindatatable.encode('utf16')

Comment: Ahh, you are cool, its work ^^ and can u answer my first question too? why i get 3 empty row and why not place into different columns?

Comment: The empty row between 1 and 4 are present because the page you parse has 2 empty TRs there. Same for the empty line at 7. In my file all the currencies are delivered. You might have a problem with Excel interpreting the "," as delimiter and list the fractions on another column, but that's a problem with the reader not the way you wrote the file. As a precaution, you might want to convert coma chars to dots. This is what the output looks at my end http://tinypic.com/r/2ed8si9/9

Comment: Ahh, so this is an Excel issue? I have to set up in the Excel settings?
But if i separate with "," sign, i get 5 columns, but i have got 4!
The last 2 columns is the value, for example Euro - 307,82

Comment: It's not really an Excel issue as much as it is an issue with the fact you try to write strings that contain commas in a comma separated values file. They will be interpreted as another column of data. You could change your separator to '.' or something else, or parse the data.text for "," and replace them by dots (because the final values you get are separated by a comma).

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced parens. `encoding` and `errors` are parameters of `file.write()` not `bytes()`.

```
file.write(bytes(header),encoding="ascii",errors="ignore")
```

Comment: I tried it, but it isnt work :
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/megoldas3.py", line 27, in <module>
    file.write(bytes(header),encoding="ascii",errors="ignore")
TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments"

Comment: Transfer the `encoding` and `errors` parameters to your call to `open`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you. Just remove `encoding="ascii",errors="ignore"` from bytes

```
# import re
# data = [['revenue', 'margins'], ['revenue', 'liquidity'], ['revenue', 'ratio'], ['revenue', 'pricing'], ['revenue', 'assets'], ['revenue', 'recent trends']]
# with open('a.txt') as f:
#   txt = f.read()
#   for d in data:
#       c1 = re.findall(d[0],txt)
#       c2 = re.findall(d[1],txt)
#       if c1 and c2:
#           print {c1[0]:len(c1),c2[0]:len(c2)}


import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

out=open("proba.csv","rb")
data=csv.reader(out)

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

maindatatable=""
soup = make_soup("https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok")

for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    datatable=""
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        datatable=datatable+","+data.text
    maindatatable = maindatatable + "\n" + datatable[1:]

header = "Penznem,Devizanev,Egyseg,Penznemforintban"
print maindatatable

file = open(os.path.expanduser("proba.csv"),"wb")
file.write(header.encode('utf-8').strip())
file.write(maindatatable.encode('utf-8').strip())
```

Comment: I tried with bytes(header) but it isnt work :\
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/megoldas3.py", line 28, in <module>
    file.write(bytes(maindatatable))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)"

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
file.write(bytes(header.encode('ascii','ignore')))
file.write(bytes(maindatatable.encode('ascii','ignore')))
```